# Inherent "in" or inherent "to"?

Tags: differences, prepositions

In a question I recently posted as to the difference between "intrinsic" and "inherent", an incidental issue arose. Which is more appropriate:

> Inherent in...

or

> Inherent to...

Gardner's Dictionary of Modern Legal Usage states that inherent takes the proposition *in*, not *to*. 
Random House Dictionary uses the following example:

> factors inherent in the situation.

Yet, Ngram viewer has similar statistics for both usages, and there seem to be different (trans-Atlantic?) intuitions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The adjectival OED sense 3 of ***inherent*** can exist without preposition (sense 3a)

> 1886   W. J. Tucker Life E. Europe 33   Our inherent indolence, our
>   apathy in times of peace is proverbial.

Where it exists in construction form (sense 3b) it is nowadays almost always with *in*, formerly with *to* and *unto*.

b. Const. in; formerly to, unto.

> 1622   G. de Malynes Consuetudo 3   The said prerogati[u]es doe also
>   appertaine to the Law-merchant as properly inherent vnto commerce.
>
> 1633   G. Herbert Faith in Temple ix,   When creatures had no reall
>   light Inherent in them.
>
> 1641   Naunton's Fragmenta Regalia sig. F2,   That height of Spirit
>   inherent to his house.
>
> 1791   J. Boswell Life Johnson anno 1752 I. 130   These sufferings
>   were aggravated by the melancholy inherent in his constitution.
>
> 1808   E. S. Barrett Miss-led General 7   That sweetness of temper
>   which is inherent to himself.
>
> 1878   H. Irving Stage 29   The love of acting is inherent in our
>   nature.

Oxford English Dictionary.

**Having noted all that, I feel certain that I have personally used it with *to***.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever said *inherent in*. It actually sounds slightly off to me; *to* certainly seems to be the right preposition.

Comment: Inherent *to*...

Answer (score 2):

I prefer "inherent to" on the grounds that both the form and the meaning of the adjective "inherent" include the notion of interiority, so the preposition "in" feels redundant. I believe (perhaps naively) that in general the preference for "to" is a Britishism. For instance, the American "different than" bothers me. Although "different" is indeed a comparative adjective, its degree is the positive, not the comparative; "than" goes with the comparative degree. Also, if we look to the verb form, we say "it differs from," not "it differs than." So I prefer "different from." This leaves the British form ("different to") unexplained, but I live in New York, so whatever, mate.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that "inherent to" sounds better. However, "inherent in" seems to be much more common; it is even used in the official US Army NCO Creed.